# Discord Type mismatches in Message components

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm re-writing a bot from js to typescript and running into a problem creating message components. In JS I was able to use ActionRowBuilder / ButtonBuilder(s) and set the components into a .send() on a Channel type. This is not the case with typescript I'm finding. This code is in the creation stage so it's a bit messy.

├── @discordjs/rest@1.3.0
├── @types/node@18.11.9
├── discord.js@14.6.0
├── dotenv@16.0.3
├── mysql2@2.3.3
├── nodemon@2.0.20
├── reflect-metadata@0.1.13
├── ts-node@10.9.1
├── typeorm@0.3.10
└── typescript@4.9.3

Type:

```
export type MessageComponents = {
    content?: string;
    messageComponents?: ActionRowBuilder<AnyComponentBuilder>[];
    messageEmbeds?: APIEmbed;
}
```

Building:

```
export default class MessageEditor {
    public buildMessage(saniResponses: SanitizedApplicationText, id: number): MessageComponents {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(ApplicationEmbedColors.PENDING)
            .setDescription(saniResponses.appText)
            .setTitle(saniResponses.appTitle);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>().addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId(`apply_button_accept_${id}`)
                .setLabel('✅ Accept')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),

            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId(`apply_button_deny_${id}`)
                .setLabel(' Deny')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
        );

        return { messageComponents: [row], messageEmbeds: embed }
    };

}
```

Using:

```
const applicationLogChannel = await client.channels.fetch(guildConfig.applicationLogChannelId) as TextChannel;
      const message = await new ApplicationFormFunctions().sanitzeApplication(client, completedApp!);
      if (!message || !message.messageComponents || !message.messageEmbeds) { return; }
      await applicationLogChannel.send({
        components: message.messageComponents,
        embeds: [message.messageEmbeds],
      });
```

The error is coming from "components: message.messageComponents on send():

```
Type 'ActionRowBuilder<AnyComponentBuilder>[]' is not assignable to type '(APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent> | JSONEncodable<APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent>> | ActionRowData<...>)[]'.
  Type 'ActionRowBuilder<AnyComponentBuilder>' is not assignable to type 'APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent> | JSONEncodable<APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent>> | ActionRowData<...>'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type 'ActionRowBuilder<AnyComponentBuilder>' but required in type 'ActionRowData<MessageActionRowComponentBuilder | MessageActionRowComponentData>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of row as Typescript is assuming the type. Add this type declaration to the row const and it should get rid of this error.

```
const row: ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>
```